# Problems combining --backends and transactional task queues in Google App Engine dev server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, backend

I was moving some functionality on a fairly sizeable App Engine application to a backend, and suddenly started getting a number of errors in places where I was using transactions while running via dev_appserver.py:

```
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 10001 Transaction(<handle: 0x1, app: "dev~MYAPPNAME", >) not found
```

I realized the problem only occurs when I run the app via --backends.  And I'm guessing the problem is occurring because I have a transaction that adds a task to a queue using "`transactional=True`", i.e.:

```
def txn():

    # make model changes

    taskqueue.add(url='/models/processupdate', params=my_params, transactional=True, queue_name='not_the_default_q')
  db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

Is this a result of the 'single threaded' nature of dev_appserver?  Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Is there a stack trace with the error? Can you amend the question with it?

Comment: Unfortunately I just have the above error.

Answer (score 0):

according to google doc [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html#Task_add), you can not name the queue if your task is transactional, the transaction task only can be added to default queue!

Comment: Where do you see this?  I can't find it on that page.  We've been using transactional queues (with names) for a while.  It only became a problem when I introduced code that used backends.

Comment: read the last sentence: transactional=False
Relevant when this method is called inside db.run_in_transaction(). Indicates that this transactional task should be added only if an enclosing datastore transaction is committed successfully. Note that this task must not have a user-specified name in this case.

Comment: Right, but that's referring to the task name, not a queue name: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Names

Comment: what's really inside your processupdate? is it looking for transactions? from the error message, it seems the transaction id did not found.

Comment: nope, not looking for transactions. just doing some fairly uninteresting datastore updates.

Comment: John, start your dev app with flag -d or --debug, it will output more debug info, so you can know what really is.